# Как отключить подключаемые скрипты в шаблоне Joomla! 3.6.5?

Tags: javascript, joomla

Создаю новый шаблон.
В место для вывода header вставлен код

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

После чего в Head выводятся строки подключения скриптов.

```
    <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js"></script>
    <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/media/system/js/caption.js"></script>
    <script>
jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
    </script>
```

Собственно говоря я не просил это делать Joomla.

Отключается ли это где то в настройках Joomla! 3.6.5 Stable?

Answer (score 0):

В Joomla! данные скрипты подгружаются автоматически из ядра, их просто не отключить, можно просто удалить загрузку данных скриптов до того как произойдёт инициализация фреймворка. Удаление можете сделать так (вставте в начале кода index.php)

```
  <?php
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js']);
unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true) . '/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js']);
 ?>
```

Удалять `caption.js` не рекомендуется, т.к влечёт за собой определённые проблемы.

Comment: Как их удалить этим способом я знаю, вопрос был как их отключить и возможно ли это.

Comment: Как уже написал, они не отключаются (в стандартном понятии), удаление самый надёжный метод при таком случае.

Comment: А какие проблемы влечет удаление caption.js ?

Comment: Логика caption очень широко используется в Joomla!, т.е она везде используется, если удалить загрузку caption.js то у вас в сайте везде будут JS ошибки , вызовов данной функции очень много и просто не найти и удалить все вызовы. Данная JS особого веса не имеет и не повлияет на скорость сайта.

Comment: Если я пишу все свои компоненты самостоятельно равно как и модули равно как и шаблон свой и весь функционал тогда я очень сильно сомневаюсь что эти вызовы появятся хоть где то.

Comment: Данный JS подгружается почти во всех  'заводских' компонентах (и модулях) ядра Joomla! например com_content или com_contact и т.д я не знаю какой вы сайт пишите на Joomla framework, но я очень сильно сомневаюсь что вы не будете использовать com_content......

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь В чём критичная надобность отключать эти скрипты?

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin Ответ на мой вопрос давно известен. А на ваш вопрос ответить наверное труднее, если вас он действительно интересует, то ответ такой. В верстке которую мы пытаемся посадить на CMS иногда присутствуют конфликтующие скрипты, и как минимум, далеко не все скрипты ядра данной CMS нужны на фронтенде.